# Behavior is wrong when adding multiple Tab components to TaskCanvasTabs in Twilio Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am developing a Twilio Flex plugin using Flex Ui version 2 (beta.1 and beta.2).
I wanted to add multiple tabs to TaskCanvasTabs and tried to write the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tab } from '@twilio/flex-ui';
import { FlexPlugin } from '@twilio/flex-plugin';

import SmsPanel from './components/SmsPanel/SmsPanel';
import IncomingVideo from './components/IncomingVideo/IncomingVideo';

const PLUGIN_NAME = 'SendSmsV2Plugin';

export default class SendSmsV2Plugin extends FlexPlugin {
  constructor() {
    super(PLUGIN_NAME);
  }

  /**
   * This code is run when your plugin is being started
   * Use this to modify any UI components or attach to the actions framework
   *
   * @param flex { typeof import('@twilio/flex-ui') }
   */
  async init(flex, manager) {
    const options = {
      align: 'end',
    };
    flex.TaskCanvasTabs.Content.add(
      <Tab label='SMS' key='sms-panel-tab-key'>
        <SmsPanel key='sms-panel-component' />
      </Tab>,
      options,
    );
    flex.TaskCanvasTabs.Content.add(
      <Tab label='Video' key='video-panel-tab-key'>
        <IncomingVideo key='incoming-video-component' />
      </Tab>,
      options,
    );
  }
}
```

When executed, the first Tab (SMS) added will be duplicated as shown below. Thereafter, each time I select the first Tab, Call tab, etc., the first Tab added will be increased.

[image]

Can someone please tell me if the specification does not allow adding multiple tabs to TaskCanvasTabs or how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried with Flex Ui version 2 (beta.3) but the behavior is the same.

It seems that this issue only happens when you try to add multiple tabs on TaskCanvasTabs

To resolve this issue you could add a Tab Group which contains Tabs

```
flex.TaskCanvasTabs.Content.add(
 <Flex.Tabs key="custom-tabs-group">
  <Flex.Tab key="conversation-note-tab" label="Conversation Notes">
    <ConversationNote key="conversation-note" />
  </Flex.Tab>
  <Flex.Tab key="label-to-conversation" label="Conversation Label">
    <AttachLabelToConversation key="add-label-to-conversation" />
  </Flex.Tab>
 </Flex.Tabs>,
{}
);
```

Use this css to adjust the tab group text

```css
/* Added CSS for merged TaskCanvasTabs into Tabs group start */
.Twilio-TaskCanvas .Twilio-TaskCanvas-default .Twilio-TaskCanvasTabs div[data-test="customer-tab-header"]:has(> div > button) button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.Twilio-TaskCanvas .Twilio-TaskCanvas-default .Twilio-TaskCanvasTabs div[data-test="customer-tab-header"]:has(> div > button) button:hover {
  background-color: unset;
}
.Twilio-TaskCanvas .Twilio-TaskCanvas-default .Twilio-TaskCanvasTabs div[data-test="customer-tab-header"]:has(> div > button) button div svg {
  display: none;
}
.Twilio-TaskCanvas .Twilio-TaskCanvas-default .Twilio-TaskCanvasTabs div[data-test="customer-tab-header"]:has(> div > button) button div:after {
  content: "Conversation Actions";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(96, 107, 133);
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
/* Added CSS for merged TaskCanvasTabs into Tabs group end */
```

Answer (score 0):

I heard the best solution.
TabPros is using the optional **uniqueName** prop instead of the key for identifying the selected tab.
So, I changed my code below. It was fixed.

```js
    flex.TaskCanvasTabs.Content.add(
      <Tab label='SMS' key='sms-panel-tab-key' uniqueName='sms-panel-tab'>
        <SmsPanel key='sms-panel-component' />
      </Tab>,
      options,
    );
    flex.TaskCanvasTabs.Content.add(
      <Tab label='Video' key='video-panel-tab-key' uniqueName='video-panel-tab'>
        <IncomingVideo key='incoming-video-component' />
      </Tab>,
      options,
    );
```

The link referenced is below.

https://github.com/twilio/flex-plugin-builder/issues/327

Comment: Add Language name in code block so that it will provide better highlights. Like for javascript

```js
Code
```

Comment: Certainly!!! Thanks for the advice.